# WCF method with custom object input

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a method that receives a custom object as input

```
[OperationContract(Name = "MyMethod")]
public CustomOutput MyMethod(CustomInput inp){}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class CustomInput 
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "x")]
        public string x { get; set; }
    }
```

I call this from a console application:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class CustomInput 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "x")]
    public string x { get; set; }
}   

class Program { 
private const string URL2 = "http://.../MyMethod";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CustomInput () { x = "pippo" });
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(str, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(URL2, content).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    } 
}
```

With this code I can call correctly MyMethod on the server, but CustomInput is always null. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: How is you endpoint binding behavior configured. Is it expecting soap, pox, json or some combination thereof?

Comment: It expects Json.

Comment: Can you show your WCF configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way the WCF service wants to understand your json is with an outer wrapper.

```
 var data= new
 {
     inp = new CustomInput({ x = "pippo" })
 };
 string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```